# How to secure API Routes in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, next.js, reactjs

So I have an external REST API with authentication to receive data.
In order to keep the authentication secure, I've made a Next.js API route as a middleware.
I'm doing the calls to the middleware to get the data from the external API.

So far so good, but now I have exposed the authenticated API to the world.
What do I have to do to allow only my app to get data from the API?

Do I have to add additional authentication between the app and the Next.js API?
If this is the case could I just call the external API directly and skip the middleware?